# python, GET request working with requests but not with aiohttp

Tags: python, python-requests, aiohttp

I am trying to scrape a page of the ft.com website with aiohttp.
I started by preparing the scraping with `requests` and it did work with no problem:

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
page= s.get("https://www.ft.com/china?page=2")
```

i can see that the page returned is the correct one with

```
print(page.text)
```

However if i try to perform the same scraping with aiohttp the page that is returned is simply an error page:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
async def get_links():
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://www.ft.com/china?page=2') as response:
            response = await response.text()
            print(response)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
results=loop.run_until_complete(get_links())
```

I can see in the printed response that this page has an "error 503"

Anyone would know how to scrape that page with aiohttp?

Comment: Works absolutely fine with me. Are you sure it goes wrong on the first request? Is there an error message with the 503? It sounds to me like you might have been rate limited or even had your IP blacklisted for excessive (unauthenticated?) requests.

Comment: @SColvin Hi thx, for your response. I also posted this question on upwork and all people involved see the same error. Note that the error code is not the status code of the response, but is within the body itself. You can see it better by adding `raise_for_status=True` as a `ClienSession()` argument.